# After an OOM how can I detect the pod that caused it?

Tags: out-of-memory, kubernetes, gcloud

I had some issues running some pods on a cluster, I want to know the way to detect which pod (and rc) is causing OOM on my nodes after the exception is thrown. I cannot access the node to check logs and `kubectl describe node` doesn't give me much information about this.

Thanks :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you try running `kubectl get events --watch` to monitor the events on k8s and monitor the pod as well with `kubectl logs -f podname`

Comment: Yes, with the events I could see the OOM but I didn't know what pod was consuming the memory.

Answer (score 2):

The only way I found to track what is happening is waiting before an OOM is thrown on the web UI [link](http://kubernetes.io/docs/user-guide/ui/) and tracking the pod's memory used (I had a node with 1.75 GB and a pod that was consuming 1.3GB). I tried to see the memory allocation with `kubectl describe node [nodename]` but I couldn't.