# How to make Jupyter Notebook Kernel throw Out Of Memory Error in Kubernetes

Tags: python, docker, kubernetes, jupyter-notebook

I am serving jupyter notebook through a Kubernetes cluster. And I've set `resources.limits` to prevent someone from draining all of the host servers memory.

While one problem is that the jupyter notebook kernels after crash and automatic restart they do not throw any OOM errors after the container exceeds the memory, which will make the user very confused.

So how can I make the jupyter notebook raise the OOM error when running with Kubernetes?

Comment: Unfortunately the real question you are asking is unclear. Could you please clarify if you are looking for a solution inside of the Kubernetes? Do you seek for a solution which will show you a message that the pod containing Jupyter Notebook was OOM killed? Or you want to inform users somehow that it was killed because of memory limit? Or you are looking for a solution that will prevent the pod from being killed because of OOM.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I do wanna seek for a solution to show a message that the pod containing Jupyter Notebook was OOM killed. I already updated my question.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but your question should be - how I can inform user that there was a problem with corresponding kernel.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have only one specific pod, you can monitor the events/logs, [as in here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38270491/6309):

```
kubectl get events --watch 
kubectl logs -f podname
```

That being said, not *all* events in a [pod lifecycle](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/pods/pod-lifecycle/) are properly reported, as shown in [`kubernetes/kubernetes` issue 38532](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/38532#issuecomment-282154320) and the (abandoned) [PR 45682](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/pull/45682).
But you should still see  `OOMKilled:true` when `docker inspect`'ing the pod.

Comment: So I still can not make the python throw an OOM error?

Comment: @aisensiy python can throw an OOM, but you need to test if a docker inspect does report it as I mention in the last part of my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Please look at solution from this post "[Jupyter notebook: memory usage for each notebook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34685825/jupyter-notebook-memory-usage-for-each-notebook)" on killing a notebook when it exceeds certain amount of memory.

There is another nice interface (like top) from [nbtop](https://github.com/iiSeymour/nbtop).